# symfony 1.4 security.yml overwrite default credential configuration

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I have a module that can be accessed only by admin, except for a single action that can be accessed by all authenticated users.

Is there a way to reset the credential for that single action? I tried to use null but still get 403 Error. Is listing all actions in security.yml the only solution?

```
default:
  credentials: [ admin ]

public:
  credentials: null
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you try to set en empty array or credential ?

```
public:
  credentials: [ ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you'll have to list all of the actions if you want fine grained control on who has access to what.

Or, another way (albeit ugly) is to set the action, which doesn't require any credentials, to `is_secure : false` and then check if they're authenticated through the action in the controller.

Also, if you want to do by using credentials, then you should set every user to have a default credential. i.e. with a credential called 'user'

Out of interest: how many actions do you have for this module?

EDIT: Also, what happens if you use a `~` instead of `null`?

Comment: So far I have about 8 actions. It is not the problem of listing the actions, but if I am afraid that if I don't restrict the default security settings and next time if I add another action and forgot to add the security settings, all users will be allowed to access to the new action. I have tried ~ too (which in yaml means null as well), but got 403 as well. I guess the best way is to supply a default credential as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write all allowed credentials inside the public action if you want to have it accesible for logged users with all credentials ([sf1.4 ad reference](http://www.symfony-project.org/reference/1_4/en/08-Security))

.. or you can open the action to the whole world:

```
default:
  is_secure: true

myPublicAction:
  is_secure: false
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I guess I am stuck as I do not have a default credentials for all authenticated users. Will add a default credential as Flukey suggested.

Comment: glad to help. Follow that sf1.4 reference if you need, its best source of info